# how to create repeatable event timer

Tags: c

Have created a digital clock for a linux framebuffer.

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm *timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
strftime(buf, strlen("DD-MMM-YYYY")+1,"%d-%b-%Y",timeinfo);
strftime(tbuf, strlen("HH:MM")+1,"%H:%M",timeinfo);
```

Now would like to have a timer to call a weather api every 30 mins or hour.  Thought of using a cron job  but am afraid writing to a file and reading from it with my program could collide.

Comment: What would collide with what? If there's a risk of "collision" can you not use a file lock, or versioned files, or something else? If this runs very infrequently, a `cron` job isn't a bad idea. That being said, most Linux distributions have some kind of "widget" system you can plug into without having to bang around with framebuffers. Are you trying to drive some little display directly?

Comment: On POSIX Systems: [alarm](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) or [timer_settime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) (see also [timer_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)).

Comment: I think I got it solved.  I set a variable to time and in the infinite while loop get the time again and use an if statement to compare difftime with a set number of seconds.